# object SequelizeInstance being pass

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am confused and I hope you can help me.  I am building an app in node.js using express.js and sequelize for my ORM.  I have created a model with the following code:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

My route looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  models.User.findAll({ }).then(function(users) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Project Insight',
      users: users
    });
  });
})
```

And I am using EJS for my templates:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {%>
      <li><%= users[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

The output I getting in my views is this:

```
[object SequelizeInstance]
[object SequelizeInstance]
[object SequelizeInstance]
[object SequelizeInstance]
```

I want to be able to pull the names from the database and I am confused about why this is giving that result.  Please let me know if there is any info you need from me.  I am new to all of this and I am at a standstill.  Thanks, in advance, for all your help.

Comment: My first guess is that you need to use `users[i].username`

Comment: ^ This is correct and you should answer it.  Also, this would work: users[i].dataValues.username Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using `dataValues` attr is not recommended. The best idea to send objects into a templating system is to use the properties directly, or use the `.toJSON()` method.

[Check N.B.](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#helper-functions-for-use-inside-gettersetter-definitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change EJS template:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {%>
      <li><%= users[i].username %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be helpful for other people:

```
model.findAll({where}).
  .then(res => {
    return res.map(row => {
      return row.dataValues
    });
  })
```

Which will return list of objects that looks like:

```
[
  {
    column1: value1,
    column2: value2,
    ...
    columnN: valueN
  }
]
```