# findAll() return [object SequelizeInstance:table name] (mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, pug

my code is :

```
app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
  Posts.findAll().then(function(posts){
    res.render(__dirname + "/home.pug", {posts:posts});
  })
```

at node and :

```
div
  each val in posts
    li= val
```

at pug, but it return:[object SequelizeInstance:mensages](mensages is the database name) instead the value

*sorry for my English and if the question is confuse*

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097020/object-sequelizeinstance-being-pass. I don't know much about pug, but it looks like you're doing the equivalent of this in JSX: **<li>{someObject}</li>**

Comment: yes it's equivalent, i see this question but what is username at it example?

Comment: Username represents a column in the database. Datatype.string would be the same as a varchar in mysql. So the table layout is copied to a javascript class so it can easily process selecting, inserting and deleting from the database

Comment: posts.conteudo.Datatype.string return:Cannot read property 'Datatype' of undefined; and post.conteudo return Cannot read property 'Datatype' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to render the [model instances](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html) of sequelize returned by `Posts.findAll()` method.

You maybe want to render a property of `post`, not the entire model instance object.

E.g.

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

class Posts extends Model {}
Posts.init(
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'posts' },
);

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, './views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Posts.findAll().then(function(posts) {
    res.render('home.pug', { posts: posts });
  });
});

(async function main() {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  //seed
  await Posts.bulkCreate([{ name: 'teresa' }, { name: 'teng' }]);
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at http://localhost:3000'));
})();
```

`views/home.pug`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title Document
    body
        div
            each val in posts
                li= val.name
```

HTML output:

[image]

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/65376890